# How to interpret intransitives in non-past tense

Tags: verbs, subsidiary-verbs, transitivity, linguistics

I've been reading linguistics books lately and they've gotten me reexamining things I've learned in Japanese textbooks for foreign learners.

Susumu Kuno's book *The Structure of the Japanese Language* states that you can use "stativity" to figure out how to interpret the non-past tense form of a verb.

Example: 猫がいる (stative) = (There) IS a cat.

Example 2: 店に行く (non-stative) = (I) WILL go to the store.

He states that stative verbs take the が particle under most circumstances. This makes it sound like all intransitive verbs would be stative.

Therefore:
ドアが閉まる (stative?) = The door IS shut. (Not the door will shut)

**Am I correct in thinking this?**

Textbooks describe intransitive verbs with ている as describing a state that's already resulted and is continuing. Transitive verbs in ている form describe an ongoing action.

Therefore:

ドアを閉めている = I'm shutting the door.

ドアが閉まっている = The door is shut (and staying that way).

**Is this a correct interpretation? How would one say that the door is shutting by itself then (like a progressive action)?

Comment: Your explanation seems a little confused -- you describe that Kuno _"states that non-stative verbs take the が particle under most circumstances. This makes it sound like all intransitive verbs would be stative."_  How so?  Also, if 閉まる is non-stative, like 行く, then it'd be "The door WILL shut", no?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mistyped. Kuno states that stative verbs take が. Thank you for pointing that out I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いる is usually used with が for the same reason English "there is" is usually followed by "a(n)" rather than "the"; ～がいる and "there is a(n) ～" are both used to [introduce something into the discourse](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010).

But "a(n)" can be used with tons of other verbs. Did your book really say you can distinguish the type of a verb by looking at if it can be used with が? I doubt it. Just because you can say ドアが閉まる in *some* circumstances doesn't mean 閉まる is a stative verb. 閉まる is an instant state-change verb (aka punctual verb). See: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

As for the last half of your question, I believe you've gotten something wrong. There are many intransitive verbs that describe an ongoing action in teiru-form (e.g., 寝ている) and there are many transitive verbs that describe the continuation of state in teiru form (e.g., 送っている). The intransitive/transitive distinction and the stative/punctual/action distinction are two different things. Please do not mix them.

- stative intransitive verb: いる, ある
- stative transitive verb: 要する
- action intransitive verb: 寝る
- action transitive verb: 食べる, 読む
- instant state change intransitive verb: 死ぬ
- instant state change transitive verb: 送る, 始める

Comment: Okay, cool makes sense. The book I mentioned is from 1970, and I think the stative idea has been built on since then. I've seen a number of books use the categories that you've descried in your answer.